# How can I write a key value to a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

There is data in the request at the name of url **'/r/rr-autocomplete/?q=string'**:

```
{"results": [{"id": "371", "text": "strstr", "selected_text": "strstr"}], "pagination": {"more": false}}
```

I want with jQuery to query the data and write the **value** of the **id** to the variable.
My js code

```
    $.get('r/rr-autocomplete/?q=string', function (data) {
    console.log(data.results)
})
```

In the console, I get the desired array, but I do not know how to write the **id** value.

```
{
"id": "371",
"text": "strstr",
"selected_text": "strstr"
}
```

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: The question is unclear but most likely one (or both) of these links has the answer: [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) and/or [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Have you tried **console.log(data.results.id)**?

Comment: @imvain2 `data.results` is an array...

Comment: @Andreas, that's what I was seeing too but then the console was outputting an object which was my confusion. But you are correct, so its just console.log(data.results[0].id)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To write to a variable id, need the following:

```
let value = data.results[0].id
```